# How to set the current time to a 31:30 hour format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an empty text box in a webpage I'm working on, I need to set the time and date to a 31.5 hour format in which the time resets upon reaching 7:30. 
Below are some examples to make my question more clear:

```
current time from "2017/02/01  1:00:00" ⇒ "2017/01/31  25:00:00"  
another example,　"2017/02/02  6:00:00" ⇒ "2017/02/01  30:00:00"
```

notice the date also continues with the time and doesn't reset until 7:30

After the time reaches 24 hours instead of resetting to 01:00:00 am, I need the value to continue to count 25:00:00, 26:00:00 etc...until it reaches 31:30:00, then reset the value at 7:30 am.

How would I do that?

Comment: it is possible and i'll try to suggest a solution, but why? -))

Comment: What part are you stuck on? What has your research told you? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not just count normally and add 7 hours? I think you need to make your own parser, as normal date parser will act in 24h range

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the overall feature. Days on Earth have at most 25 hours (thanks to daylight saving time). If you are coding in another calendar (as to power an app in another planet) you won't be able to use JavaScript date features and you'll basically have to roll your own format. That's trivial (if you don't need complex calculations) or horrible (if you need them).

Comment: What will `2017/02/01  8:30:00` convert to? Is it still the same or will it be `2017/02/01  1:00:00`??

Comment: @marmeladze some countries use this system

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it is still has only 24 hours, instead of starting from 1 am, the time starts from 7:30 am

Comment: @Oliver the time will reset after 31:30 to 7:31 am, so 8:30 am will still be 8:30 am, 8:30 pm however is 20:30. in this system the morning hours of 1:00 am to 7:30 am will be replaced by 25 to 31:30.

Comment: then the logic is quite simple (in pseudo code): `if time < 7:30 then date.addDay(-1) and time + 24:00`

Comment: @Oliver thanks man, will try the code you provided